# Is it possible to distinguish between Building and Cleaning in the scheme's Build post-action?

Tags: xcode, build-system

When adding a Run Script to the Build Post-actions in my Xcode scheme, I've noticed that it will run the script both after building, but also after cleaning.

Some previous out of date questions have discussed this, and suggest that the `ACTION` environment variable contains information as to the action being run, but I this seems to be empty for me both when selecting to "Provide build settings from" my target, or "None".  It seems that this either was past functionality, or the case with the old build system.

Is there a well-support/convenient way to distinguish between these two actions in this post-action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My current solution:

1) Add a Run Script to the end of my build phases that touches a file in `/tmp/`, eg:

```sh
touch /tmp/xcode-did-run-build
```

2) Then in the Post-Action build script, check to see if this file exists:

```sh
if [ -e /tmp/xcode-did-run-build ]; then
    # Build/Archive was run
else
    # Build/ was not run, presumably clean was called, but I don't know 
    # for certain if other actions can call the Build post-actions.
fi
```